# Unexpected warning in click cli development with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, click, warnings

I got a warning that i don't understand while developing a cli using click and python

The error is detected on line 15 of the test_hello.py file:
Expected type 'BaseCommand', got '(name: Any) -> Any' instead

```
test_hello.py

import click
import pytest as pytest
from click.testing import CliRunner
from cli.main import hello


@pytest.fixture
def runner() -> click.testing.CliRunner:
    """Fixture for invoking command-line interfaces."""
    return click.testing.CliRunner()


def test_hello_world():
    runner = CliRunner()
--> result = runner.invoke(hello, ['Peter'])
    assert result.exit_code == 0
    assert result.output == 'Hello Peter!\n'
```

```
main.py

import click


@click.command()
@click.argument("name")
def hello(name):
    click.echo("Hello %s!" % name)
```

and directory structure is like this:

```
.
├── build
│   ├── bdist.linux-x86_64
│   └── lib
│       └── cli
├── cli
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-311.pyc
│   │   ├── main.cpython-311.pyc
│   │   └── test_main.cpython-311-pytest-7.4.4.pyc
│   └── tests
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __pycache__
│       └── test_hello.py
├── cli.egg-info
│   ├── ...
├── dist
│   └── cli-0.1.0-py3.11.egg
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
└── venv
    ├── bin
    │   ├── ...
    ├── lib
    │   └── python3.11
    └── pyvenv.cfg
```

If anyone can explain whats going on it would be very helpful, thanks in advance! :)

I want the warning to be removed so my CI tests can pass

Comment: Please include the version of Click package.